# How would you find a complete list of a software's vulnerabilities?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities

I'm interested in the number of vulnerabilities over time, not in specific information about the vulnerabilities. I also don't expect any list to be completely authoritative. But what list could I consult to get an idea of the number of vulnerabilities for a specific software over time?